# Trying to automatically download backups stored on a virtual server using SFTP

Tags: ftp, sftp, vps

I have a centOS WHM where I store multiple cPanels. I need to SFTP into this server and download the cPanel backups which over daily/weekly/monthly. I'll probably just grab the weekly backups.

I had an application that let me FTP into servers and automate backups, Auto FTP Manager. It works great but it's not compatible with SFTP unfortunately.

Does anyone know of any free alternatives?

Comment: Did you look into rsync, that can operate over ssh and "mirror" a folder with your backups to alternative locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinSCP to automate download of the backups or to automate synchronization of the backups and their local copy.

For details, see the [guide to automating file transfers from FTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

You can then [schedule the script using Windows Scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try psftp.  It's available for download at the same place where you get PuTTY  (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).